# Error using RegexLiteKit to draw rout on mapview

Tags: regex, ios4

In one of my iphone projects I have used the RegexLiteKit for drawing rout in my mapview. While compiling the following failures are showing,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_uregex_start", referenced from:
      _rkl_performRegexOp in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_findRanges in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_end", referenced from:
      _rkl_performRegexOp in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_findRanges in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_setText", referenced from:
      _rkl_clearCacheSlotSetTo in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_setCacheSlotToString in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_find", referenced from:
      _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_findNext", referenced from:
      _rkl_search in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_u_errorName", referenced from:
      _rkl_NSExceptionForRegex in RegexKitLite.o
      _rkl_userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
  "_u_strlen", referenced from:
      _rkl_userInfoDictionary in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_reset", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_appendReplacement", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_appendTail", referenced from:
      _rkl_replaceAll in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_open", referenced from:
      _rkl_getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_groupCount", referenced from:
      _rkl_getCachedRegex in RegexKitLite.o
  "_uregex_close", referenced from:
      _rkl_clearCacheSlotRegex in RegexKitLite.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to make RegexLiteKit work? please help..

Answer (score 18):

- go to your target build settings
- search for `linker flags`
- double tap near `other linker flags` and add `-licucore`

done

Answer (score 14):

Add libicucore framework to your project solve this issue and for reference go through this link http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-regular-expression-tutorial-regexkitlite-framework/

Comment: can you please explain why his happens? i have same problems and this solved me.. thnx

Comment: Some of the classes are linked up with libicucore framework so.

Answer (score 10):

I have solve this issue by adding libicucore framework to my project.The way to add libicucore frame work **Build Settings-> Linking->Other Linker Flags --> -licucore**

Answer (score 9):

You need to set linker flags below are steps to do same.
Go to Build Settings-> Linking->Other Linker Flags --> **-licucore**

Don't forget to add **-** above **licucore**

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using arc for project then please add compiler flag `-fno-objc-arc` for `RegexKitLite.m`.

Next you must add Other linker flag by follow:

Build Settings > Linking > **Other Linker Flags**

Add:

```
-licucore
-ObjC
-lc++
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 9.2 and Xcode 7, I solved the problem as follow

1. Click your project
2. Click target
3. Click "Build Phases" tab
4. Double click RegexKitLie.m
5. Enter -fno-objc-arc in opend box
6. Done and enjoy.